# Is it possible to get ALL response headers from from Apache using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I get the request headers from the browser like this.

```html
<?php
$DataFromBrowser='';
$DataToBrowser='';

$headers =  getallheaders();
foreach($headers as $key=>$val){
  $DataFromBrowser = $DataFromBrowser .  $key . ': ' . $val . "\n";
}



//echo get_raw_http_request();
echo "Data from browser";
echo '<textarea rows="12" style="width:100%;">' .  $DataFromBrowser  . '</textarea>';

?>
```

And the output will look like this.

> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cookie: foo=bar
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
> Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
> Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
> Sec-Fetch-Site: none
> Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

Now I want to do exactly the same but for the response headers from the server. I'm aware I can do the following but it will create another connection I need the response headers of the current served page.

```
<?php
$URL = 'https://www.google.com';

$headers = get_headers($URL);
foreach($headers as $value) {
    echo $value;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

If I change the above to http://127.0.0.1 It get's it self in a deadlock and will loop until it bombs out.

The response headers should look like this.

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2022 16:53:45 GMT
> Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1j PHP/8.0.3
> X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.3
> Content-Length: 589
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: What does "If I change the above to http://127.0.0.1 It get's it self in a deadlock" mean? You have the power of "you control this code, on your own computer", so find out what it's actually doing: does it even load that script or does a completely different file kick in because you're already running a server on port 80? Does it make it past get_headers? Do you have warnings/errors turned on? etc. etc.

Comment: Do you mean [`headers_list()`](http://www.php.net/headers_list)? Also check `apache_response_headers()`

Comment: You can not get the response headers for a request while _inside_ that request on the server side. The web server that's wrapping the PHP call (and any intermediary caches/proxies) will add headers after PHP has completed its processing. Do you need all the headers? Or just those that PHP itself might be adding?

Comment: Please only use code snippets for html/css/javascript.

Comment: _"If I change the above to `http://127.0.0.1` It get's it self in a deadlock and will loop until it bombs out."_ - that would not perhaps be because the script code you have shown, is also triggered by requesting that very same URL ...?